# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator when using Jersey + AWS S3 sdk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jersey, apache-httpcomponents

I have included the *aws-java-sdk-s3* dependency in my existing jersey project.

I have a post method which will upload an image to S3. Whenever I invoke AmazonS3Client I'm getting this error.

Here is the stack trace.

```
[org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.<init>(Lorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeRegistry;Lorg/apache/http/conn/DnsResolver;)V] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.<init>(Lorg/apache/http/conn/scheme/SchemeRegistry;Lorg/apache/http/conn/DnsResolver;)V
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager.createConnectionOperator(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:138)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:112)
    at com.amazonaws.http.ConnectionManagerFactory.createPoolingClientConnManager(ConnectionManagerFactory.java:39)
    at com.amazonaws.http.HttpClientFactory.createHttpClient(HttpClientFactory.java:113)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:217)
    at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:137)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:482)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:462)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:444)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:416)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:398)
```

However when I tried creating a webapp without the Jersey dependency and uploading a image via servlet call, it worked without any error.

Please let me know if I have missed some dependencies.

Comment: Improved readability, code formatting

Comment: Had you solved it?

Comment: Yes, I created an entirely new app and included all the dependencies as previous, I suspect it was some class path issue with eclipse.